# Persisting arptables on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, networking, arp, ufw

I am using Ubuntu 18 with UFW as the basic firewall.

I need to restrict some ARP traffic from the box, and I can that by using the following arptables command:

```
sudo arptables -I OUTPUT --source-mac source-mac-here --destination-mac destination-mac-here -j DROP
```

However, when I reboot the machine the arptables entries are lost.

How can I persist the arptable entries across a reboot?
I need this to work with the existing UFW config.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a script with your ARP config to the network-interface deamon.
Take a look here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection

Alternatively you can disable networking on startup, and run a script on /after login.